# How to extract syntactic features with python using corenlp?

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to extract syntactic information from a sentence. What I have tried is

```
corenlp_dir = "/home/corenlp-python/stanford-corenlp-full-2013-11-12/"
parser = corenlp.StanfordCoreNLP(corenlp_path=corenlp_dir)

result_json = json.loads(parser.parse("I am Alice."))
#pprint.pprint(result_json)
for sentence in result_json["sentences"]:
    pprint.pprint(sentence["parsetree"]) 
    print type(sentence["parsetree"])
```

I only get

```
--># u'(ROOT (S (NP (PRP I)) (VP (VBP am) (NP (NNP Alice))) (. .)))'
<type 'unicode'>
```

and the result is a string, not a parsertree.
However, what I really want is like a syntactic feature that can be used to do text classification. How to extract particular syntactic features from the result above?
I have no ideas about how to do it. Could anyone help me or give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You'd better understand the format of the result first, and write your own code to demonstrate/plot the results if you want.

Take your result for example,
one smallest unit could be *(PRP I)*, which means 'I' plays the role of 'Pronoun' in this sentence, and if you look out current bracket, *(NP (PRP I))* means this Pronoun is a Noun Phrase(NP). etc
And this is how you get a parse tree from bottom up, in the end you will reach 'ROOT'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am a newbie of NLP. I have understood the meaning of the "parsetree". But I really have no idea about how to syntactically tag the word, such as "I",  it is not the same with POS. Could you give me some idea?

Comment: The POS tag of 'I' is 'PRP', within the closest brackets. This process is called POS tagging. Then you get this PRP is a 'NP'(noun phrase), a NP could be a single word, but usually a phrase. Now you get some bigger units, and dividing the sentence into parts is called chunking. From units you construct a tree-like structure, and the whole process is to analysis the syntax of this sentence.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer,but what is ROOT's function? For example,in Production Rule, such as S->NP+PRP, we don't need the ROOT, right?

Comment: ROOT is where the sentence starts, I think you can ignore it like that. While I got really confused when you wrote S->NP+PRP, where PRP is the component of NP which makes '+' nonsense, and how could a sentence S be complete if there are only a NP plus a PRP?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I want to extract the syntactic feature of the sentence"I am Alice".What you mean is that I can only obtain S->NP+VP+NP? and PRP, VBP, NNP in this parsetree make nonsense?

Comment: I dunt know how you define your syntactic features. A parsetree in a whole might be fine; using PRP etc. should also be fine. What I said was S->NP+PRP doesn't look like a correct/complete formula.

Comment: Yeah, now I know S->NP+PRP may not a complete formula, thanks for your kindhearted explanation. To be honest, as I am a newbie of NLP, I do not know how to define syntactic features exactly. What I only have is the stanford corenlp tool. And I have to use the tool to obtain some features that will be used for text classification. Therefore, Could you please give me some idea on how to extract syntactic features from the parsetree or could you show me some example code that can inspire me?